# Why does geoprocessing service tool Table to Excel always put output in scratch folder and not folder specified?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, scratch-workspace

I have the output set to a registered folder that arcgisserver has permissions to access, it works fine when I run it locally but when I run it through the web it always sends my output file to a scratch workspace instead of the specified folder.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shortest answer**: Because thats how GP Services work, they handle the output, writing to a known location, that being the scratchFolder (or scratch.gdb) in the arcgisserver directories.

**More explained**:
I'd really caution against trying to output to a given spot. The GP Server framework outputs to a scratchfolder in a GUID (long unique name) folder for a number of reasons. The most important one being this location is a safe, known to exist location where another process wont interfere. It is the framework that handles sending back the output to the client and the client does something with that result.

If you absolutely want to venture down this path you're going to have to put your workflow into a script. Do all the processing (table to excel). At the end of the script have a folder variable referenced where you want to output to, `myfolder = 'c:/temp/excel'`. Have that folder referenced in your data store so it doesnt get copied during publishing. Copy the output you created from the table to excel tool into this registered folder. [ you're done. ] Now be aware you're now on the hook for having unique output file names, cleaning that directory up and worrying about 2 people executing the service at the same time.

Comment: I went ahead and left it in the scratch workspace, and sent the email from that file.  It does help with deleting duplicate data that would build up, and keeping other processes from interfering.  Appreciate the answer!